# Frequent Kusto Error: Insufficient winsock resources available to complete socket connection initiation

Tags: azure-data-explorer

From the last few days we have been trying to hunt down some kusto query failures. Time and again we see the following error.

- Have looked into any increase in ingestions for the past few days and don't see any.

  - In few scenarios we use direct ingestion, can this be the issue?
- Does this error mean that the server is out of sockets? If so, what is generally the cause for that? ANd ho can that be alleviated?
- Couldn't find any troubleshooting guide for this.

Happy to provide more details as needed.

Failure details: Query execution has resulted in error (0x8013153D): Partial query failure: 0x8013153D (message: 'Insufficient winsock resources available to complete socket connection initiation. ==> ExecuteRemoteSubQuery failure: ', details: 'Source: mscorlib System.InsufficientMemoryException: Insufficient winsock resources available to complete socket connection initiation. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full 11.0.0.82:23107 Server stack trace: Exception rethrown at [0]: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- [0]Kusto.Data.Exceptions.KustoDataStreamException: Query execution has resulted in error (0x8013153D): Partial query failure: 0x8013153D (message: 'Insufficient winsock resources available to complete socket connection initiation. ==> ExecuteRemoteSubQuery failure: ', details: 'Source: mscorlib System.InsufficientMemoryException: Insufficient winsock resources available to complete socket connection initiation. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full 11.0.0.82:23107 Server stack trace: Exception rethrown at [0]: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- Timestamp=2020-12-04T17:47:28.3230123Z

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you open a support ticket for your resource, via the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com)